# How can I achieve a mutli-level sort of a field that is being pulled in via a relationship from multiple content types in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type called Session which uses the Inline Entity Form module to create/entity-reference three other content types: Material, Audio Archive, and Adobe Connect (AC) Archive.

In the view, I only want to show nodes from the Material, Audio Archive, and AC Archive content types. But I want to also show the Session node titles each of these nodes are related to.

There are four columns in this table view:

- Date
- Title (this is the title of the Material, Audio Archive, and AC Archive nodes)
- Item Type (for Audio Archive and AC Archive, it shows the name of the content type; for Material, since that content type has several subtypes, it shows the name of the subtype -- if no content type is selected, it shows the name of the content type)
- Title of Related Session (this is the title field of the Session content type that the other nodes are related to)

The title of the Session is showing up in the last column for each node, which is good (although I'm not sure how that was achieved as I inherited this project from a much more experienced developer).

I'm trying to resolve two related issues:

1) How do I do a multi-level sort in views?

I want to first sort by Date (descending), then by Title of Related Session (ascending), then by Title (ascending).

I want to achieve this regardless of content type/subtype.

2) Right now, if I want to sort by Date or by Title (as just a single-level sort), the sort is working properly. If I try to sort by Title of Related Session though, it's not working properly.

So if I try to sort by the Title of Related Session column, here's what happens:

Materials with a subtype selected gets sorted (I think this has to do with the fact that in the Fields section of views, Materials is listed last as there's some rewriting going on), and then after that, Audio Archive, AC Archive, and Materials with no subtype aren't getting sorted at all. I think figuring out how to even sort this at a single-level sort will make the multi-level sort work properly when I get to that (which is my true issue/solution I'm trying to achieve).

Also, I tried to re-create the relationship between, say, Session and Materials and Session and Audio Archive myself but when I try to add the relationship, I'm unable to see the Session content type at all so I'm very puzzled by that. Any help with that would be greatly appreciated too, thank you.

Please note that I'm not a developer so I'm unable to write any code and I unfortunately don't have access to one so any solution (if any) would need to configuration-based only.